# How do I install maatwebsite/excel?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-6

I'm trying to install [maatwebsite/excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel); however, I can't get it to work.

I tried deleting the `composer.lock` file and running:

```sh
composer install
composer update
```

I also tried:

```sh
composer require maatwebsite/excel --update-with-dependencies
```

Neither method worked.

The error I received was:

```
Problem 1
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.10 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.11 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.12 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.13 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
 .
 .
 .
 .

- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.14 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.15 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].   
- Installation request for maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.10, 3.1.11, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 3.1.14, 3.1.15, 3.1.16, 3.1.17, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.7, 3.1.8, 3.1.9, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Users\user\Downloads\php-7.3.8-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used 
by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my stuation, the error happened because composer wasn't able to load
the `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` package. Normally, composer is capable of installing dependencies. However, there were some missing php extension on the server – like php zip. Once I installed those extensions, the problem was solved.

Instead of ignoring requirements, I suggest you to look into the source of the problem.

Comment: This worked for me: *composer require maatwebsite/excel -W* (Which the [-W] means require all dependencies update)

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, it was a dependency error. To ignore this dependency requirement run:

```sh
composer require maatwebsite/excel --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: `maatwebsite/excel 3.1.10 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`, so you should not require 'maatwebsite/excel', require 'phpoffice/phpspreadsheet' instead.

Comment: Thanks you so much it work for me laravel 8

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip&&sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

it helped me

Answer (score 3):

GD (GIF Draw) extension is required for this package.
You need to enable the gd extension from php.ini file.

search for this file in php.ini: `extension=gd`

Comment: This is the real answer!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your php.ini file and look for the line
`**;extension=gd**`     and change it to
`**extension=gd**`

If this line is not there then look for   `**gd**`    only and un comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but this worked for me.

sudo apt-get install php-zip&&sudo apt-get install php-gd
I was getting.
maatwebsite/excel 3.1.10 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0].

As Teoman Tıngır said Composer should update dependencies but sometime due to some missing extension it cannot be able to do that that's why these errors come up.

Answer (score 0):

go to php.ini and uncomment(extension=gd) remove ; before extension=gd
it helped me